# Can not login to drupal site in safari

Tags: caching, safari, drupal-7

I have a drupal site running in https.It does not have any problem while login in firefox,chrome and opera but in safari not works.The site home page is opening in safari but when I try to login it redirect me to the home page.

Site cache is disabled and I have also cleared the safari cache many times but no luck after login.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am able to login to my drupal site in safari.Actually now I am redirecting https:// to https:// and it is working fine in all browsers.

I think safari treated it as bad url with "www".